# What does the "diff --git" output in "git diff" refer to?

Tags: git

When I run `git diff`, the output begins with:

```
diff --git a/foo/bar b/foo/bar
```

If I try to run plain old `diff --git`, I'm told that the `--git` option doesn't exist (obviously, I guess, it would seem silly for a low-level tool to know about a specific DVCS). There's no mention of it in the `man` page as well. Where does this come from?

Comment: It is confusing indeed how git includes these commands in such a weird way.

Comment: The particular output is  added here:https://github.com/git/git/commit/b58f23b38a9a9f28d751311353819d3cdf6a86da and the reasoning for it is buried somewhere in here: http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0505/3812.html

Comment: Someone removed it, but I originally had an `osx` tag to indicate that this was the `diff` that ships with macOS, and the GNU tools might *diff*er.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's an "imaginary diff option", used to indicate to the reader that it's not *just* the output of running the `diff` command. For example, in git's own git repo:

```
$ git diff HEAD~1..HEAD | head
diff --git Documentation/git.txt Documentation/git.txt
index bd659c4..7913fc2 100644
--- Documentation/git.txt
+++ Documentation/git.txt
@@ -43,6 +43,11 @@ unreleased) version of Git, that is available from the 'master'
 branch of the `git.git` repository.
 Documentation for older releases are available here:

+* link:v2.10.0/git.html[documentation for release 2.10]
+
$
```

The `diff` command itself, if you invoked it with the same file name twice, would show no differences. `git` presumably creates temporary files corresponding to two different versions of `Documentation/git.txt` and feeds them to `diff` -- but the names of those temporary files would not be useful. I think `git diff` massages the output of `diff` to make it more meaningful to the reader. (*This speculation was not entirely correct. See below.*)

Diving into the git source code, `diff.c` has the string `"diff --git"` hardwired as a string literal:

```
strbuf_addf(&header, "%s%sdiff --git %s %s%s\n", line_prefix, meta, a_one, b_two, reset);
```

And looking into the history of `diff.c` for the earliest version that contains that string:

```
$ git log -n 1 b58f23b3
commit b58f23b38a9a9f28d751311353819d3cdf6a86da
Author: Junio C Hamano <junkio@cox.net>
Date:   2005-05-18 09:10:47 -0700

    [PATCH] Fix diff output take #4.

    This implements the output format suggested by Linus in
    <Pine.LNX.4.58.0505161556260.18337@ppc970.osdl.org>, except the
    imaginary diff option is spelled "diff --git" with double dashes as
    suggested by Matthias Urlichs.

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <junkio@cox.net>
    Signed-off-by: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@osdl.org>
$
```

Presumably `<Pine.LNX...>` is the message-id of some email message in a mailing list somewhere. In any case, this commit message makes it clear that `diff --git` is an "imaginary diff option".

[This email message](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0505/3812.html), cited by nos in a comment, appears to be part of the discussion that led to this.

**UPDATE:** I speculated above that `git diff` massages the output of `diff`, adding this information. I just tried running `git diff` under `strace`. It doesn't actually invoke the `diff` command, or any other command. Rather, all the output is printed by the `git` process itself, and apparently it computes the differences internally. This behavior might also depend on the version of `git` (I'm using 2.23.0), the `diff` command(s) available, and the arguments used.

I'll note that GNU diff has a `--label=LABEL` option that *could* be used for this kind of thing:

```
'-L LABEL'
'--label=LABEL'
     Use LABEL instead of the file name in the context format (*note
     Context Format::) and unified format (*note Unified Format::)
     headers.  *Note RCS::.
```

but `git diff` doesn't use it, at least in the one case I tried, and I don't see a  reference to it in the git sources.

Answer (score 3):

The `--git` is to mean that diff is in the "git" diff format. It doesn't refers to and option of the `/usr/bin/diff` command You can find the list of [diff format](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-format) documentation. Other formats are:

- `diff --combined`
- `diff --cc`
- `diff --summary`

Answer (score 1):

As Keith mentioned, in GNU diff (check your version with `diff -v`), you can have git-style patches by using `--label` like so:

a single file from a backup

```sh
diff -u --label a/path/to/file.ext --label b/path/to/file.ext path/to/file.ext~ path/to/file.ext
```

or from STDIN

```sh
command_that_outputs_previous_version | diff -u --label a/path/to/file.ext --label b/path/to/file.ext - path/to/file.ext
```

You can use those commands in a loop of files from `find`, etc. Where one side of a comparison does not exist, e.g. new files, compare with `/dev/null`.